# Re-call a confirm window if user chose "Ok"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm somewhat just getting started w/ jQuery and I'd like to find out how to re-call the confirm window after the user chose "Ok". I know that the confirm box returns a Boolean and I'll be needing to use an if-statement. But how do I re-call an anonymous function(if possible)? I have a feeling I'll be needing a recursive function, but I'm not quite sure.

```
$(function)(){
 $("#diceButton").click(function(){
  var dice = Math.floor((Math.random()*12)+1);
   var answer=confirm("You rolled "+dice+"! Roll again or quit?");
    if(answer===true)
  });
 });
```

This is where I'm stuck at, if anyone can point me towards the right direction!

Comment: You need to recall `confirm` or the anonymous click handler ?

Comment: replace   `var answer=confirm("You rolled "+dice+"! Roll again or quit?");
    if(answer===true)` by `if(confirm("You rolled "+dice+"! Roll again or quit?"))`

Comment: Since I'd like for the dice to be a new value, I'd like to re call the anonymous click handler.

Comment: @SKSam Just modified your code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no rule in JavaScript that anonymous function should not have name. You can have a name for anonymous function and that name can be accessed within the function only.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#diceButton").click(function diceClick(){
        var dice = Math.floor((Math.random()*12)+1);
        if(confirm("You rolled "+dice+"! Roll again or quit?")) {
            diceClick();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="diceButton">Dice</button>
```

Comment: Ahh thank you! This really helped me with understanding anonymous functions. I was thinking about whether or not naming an anonymous function was correct earlier...thanks again!

Comment: @SKSam No problem. Be aware, you can't access `diceClick` outside of the function body. It will be visible only within it's function body

Comment: Umm, anonymous functions by definition don't have a name. And older browsers do not support creating a named function as a parameter.

Comment: Yup! I believe the values of the variables within diceClick are also not accessible outside? Because if so, then great; I plan on using the same variable through different functions.

Comment: @papirtiger Once you give name to anonymous function, they are called as inline named functions.

Comment: @papirtiger that's true and that's what caused my confusion earlier. I watched a lecture of someone saying that 
    var anonymous = function(){} 
is still anonymous because it's just associating a function with an object. (Not sure if I'm correct, just some insight from a lecture I watched)

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu thanks I can never remember that name - but if i remember correctly inline named functions have a bunch of gotchas that won't be sorted until ES6...

Comment: @papirtiger Can you send me the link that explains about those gotchas ? I can have a look at that :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function rollDice(){
  var dice = Math.floor((Math.random()*12)+1);
  if(confirm("You rolled "+dice+"! Roll again or quit?")) {
   rollDice();
  }
}
    
rollDice();
```

Or a jQuery solution using events:

```js
$("#diceButton").on('dice.roll', function(){
  var dice = Math.floor((Math.random()*12)+1);
 var $self = $(this);
  if(confirm("You rolled "+dice+"! Roll again or quit?")) {
    $self.trigger('dice.roll');
  }
});

$("#diceButton").click(function(){
  $(this).trigger('dice.roll');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="diceButton">Test Your Luck</button>
```

Or an even simpler solution - just reclick the button:

```js
$("#diceButton").click(function(){
  var dice = Math.floor((Math.random()*12)+1);
  var $self = $(this);
  if(confirm("You rolled "+dice+"! Roll again or quit?")) {
    $self.click();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it into a function and call it on click

```
$("#diceButton").click(roll_dice);

  function roll_dice() {
    var dice = Math.floor((Math.random()*12)+1);
    var answer=confirm("You rolled "+dice+"! Roll again or quit?");
    if(answer===true) {
        roll_dice();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't mention it in the post but I'm trying to focus on using anonymous functions, but this was very insightful as well!

Answer (score 0):

Extract as function:

```
function rollDice()
{
 var dice = Math.floor((Math.random()*12)+1);
   var answer=confirm("You rolled "+dice+"! Roll again or quit?");
    if(answer===true)
    {
      rollDice();
    }
    else return;
}
```

Then call it:

```
$(function(){
 $("#diceButton").click(function(){
   rollDice();
  });
 });
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/20h8g5wt/1/